# Why does a  blob with filename $$$.$$$ appear in Azure directory listing?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Does anyone know why when I list a blobs in a directory like this:

```
var container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
var blobs = container.GetDirectoryReference(fileStroageLocation).ListBlobs().ToList();
```

I find the two files I uploaded and an additional blob with the filename $$$.$$$. If I use an Azure file storage browser CloudXplorer I don't see the file.

I can filter it out by ignoring that filename however. Just wondered why it was there? If there is special meaning to it? How it got created? If there is a better way to exclude. Google doesn't seem very helpful when searching for "$$$.$$$"!

Thanks

Graeme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't remember which, but some storage tools create that file as a placeholder when you create directories in their UI. Because blob storage doesn't have a concept of a directory, there's no way to create `container/dir`, so some tools create `container/dir/$$$.$$$` instead.

If CloudXplorer isn't showing you the file, my guess is CloudXplorer is the tool that created it.