# How to create empty folder in azure blob storage

Tags: azure, directory, blob

How to create empty folder in azure blob storage just like empty folder in tool "Azure Explorer"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Technically speaking, you can't have an empty folder in Azure Blob Storage as blob storage has a 2 level hierarchy - blob container and blob. You essentially create an illusion of a folder by prefixing the file name with the folder name you like e.g. assuming you want a style sheet (say site.css) in say `css` folder, you name the stylesheet file as `css/site.css`.

What some of the tools do is in order to create an empty folder, they create a zero byte blob and prefix it with the name of the folder and then don't show that zero byte blob. If you want, you can do that.

Comment: thank you so much, i also try to create a zero byte blob, but i do not know how to hide this file

Comment: So you can't really hide the blob. What you do is when you list blobs, you remove the blob from the blobs list and show other blobs. However please keep in mind that folks will be able to see this blob if they are trying to access your blob storage through some other tool.

Comment: Good answer. Some tools use $$$.$$$ as a convention for the the "blank blob" . See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445830/why-does-a-blob-with-filename-appear-in-azure-directory-listing

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it with Linux.

```
az storage blob upload --container-name <container name> --name <folder name> -f /dev/null --account-name <storage account name>
```

- the file name ends with a trailing slash (e.g. `myfolder/`)
- the CLI expects a file, so just upload nothing (i.e. `/dev/null/`)

Answer (score 0):

Gaurav's point is good to understand.

Though in practice, when using `hdfs` cli in bash, I've found you *can't* just rename the file (using `mv` as you normally would) if the sub-directory you're attempting to 'create' doesn't already exist.

You can however use 
`hdfs dfs -mkdir -p wasb://container-name@account-name.blob.core.windows.net/sub-dir-name`

Followed by 
`hdfs dfs -mv wasb://container-name@account-name.blob.core.windows.net/file-name wasb://container-name@account-name.blob.core.windows.net/sub-dir-name/file-name`

Answer (score 0):

If you have An ADLS Gen2 it is possible. For further details, please refer to the following URL [Creating a hierarchical container directory using PowerShell in Azure ADLS Gen2 storage account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64951215/creating-a-hierarchical-container-directory-using-powershell-in-azure-adls-gen2)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: The link now returns 404 (Page Not Found).

Answer (score 0):

Uploading an empty file in the directory you want to create, and then deleting it worked for me.